# C# winforms, OLEDB reading excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, oledb

I have some process that reades an excel file, but i get the data truncated to 255 chars. I know i can fix it if I change the TypeGuessRows in regedit, but I need other solutions. I need fix it in the code, is it posible?

Comment: Format your excel columns to type "Memo", this article may help you (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91bdf4cd-7f80-4516-a2e1-7a71703340c4/255-character-limit-oledb-c-inconsistent-results?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: TypeGuessRows does not affect how many characters you can read as a string. It's how many rows OLEDB reads to determine the data type of a column. The default is 8.